# how do i solve this probability question?

Tags: probability

can someone explain step by step how to solve this?

A group of individuals containing b boys and g girls is lined up
in random order; that is, each of the (b + g)! permutations is assumed to be equally likely. Let Gi be the event the i-th person is a girl. Find P(Gi).

Comment: The probability that a girl is on the first position is just $\frac{g}{b+g}$ This probability is equal for all positions.

Comment: thanks, that's an easy way of looking at it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How many ways can you order the $b+g$ people such that the $i$-th
>   person is a girl?

Clearly, there are $g$ ways to choose a girl to place in the $i$-th position. There are then $(b+g-1)!$ ways to arrange the rest of the people. Therefore,
$$P(G_i)=\frac{g\cdot(b+g-1)!}{(b+g)!}=\frac{g}{b+g}.$$